# Get the shortest list prefix satisfying a condition

Tags: haskell

Say I have a list and want to get the shortest prefix of the list such that it satisfies a condition. For example, let's say I want to get a prefix of a list of ints which sums to a least the given number. One way to do it:

```
module ListPrefix where

import Data.Maybe

lpref :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
lpref w xs =
  let f l r s
        | s >= w    = Just (reverse l)
        | null r    = Nothing
        | otherwise = f (head r : l) (tail r) (s + head r)
  in f [] xs 0

main = do
  print $ lpref 48 [1..100]
```

Is there a way to write this without using manual recursion?

**Edit:**

A bit better version based on [Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem)'s suggestion:

```
lpref2 :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
lpref2 w xs =
  let f t@(ys, s) e = if s >= w then t else (e : ys, s + e)
      (fs, s) = foldl f ([], 0) xs
  in if s >= w then Just (reverse fs) else Nothing
```

Let me know if this can be improved!

Comment: Hint: take a look at folding, use a 2-tuple as state that contains the required amount necessary, and the list constructed thus far.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem! I've added a version based on your suggestion, looks a bit better, though lmk if you think there's an even better way. Also, won't this iterate the whole list always? I.e. it won't short-circuit if the result is found near the beginning of the list and needlessly iterate through the whole list, right?

Comment: Consider selecting the first suitable candidate from the list of [prefixes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits).

Comment: Thanks @Khuldraesethna'Barya - `inits` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple, concise way, though probably not the most efficient:

```hs
import Data.List (find, inits)

lpref :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
lpref w = find (\xs -> sum xs >= w) . inits
```

As for your attempt, the first thing to note is that on regular lists, `foldl` is always wrong. You should always use either `foldl'` or `foldr` instead. Also, testing `null` and then using `head` and `tail` as an anti-pattern.

Here's what I'd do to maximize efficiency:

```hs
lpref :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
lpref w xs
  | 0 >= w = Just []
  | otherwise = foldr go mempty xs 0 id
  where
    go :: Int -> (Int -> ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Maybe [Int]) -> Int -> ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Maybe [Int]
    go x acc s f
      | s' >= w = Just $ f [x]
      | otherwise = acc s' (f . (x:))
      where s' = x + s
```

This is also maximally lazy. `lpref 6 (1:2:3:undefined)` returns `Just [1,2,3]`.

Comment: Great, thanks for both solutions and other notes! The second one is definitely interesting.